# WPF unity Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism, modularity

I am getting the following error when trying to Initialise the Module using Unity and Prism.  The DLL is found by

```
return new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
```

The dll is found and the Name is Found

```
  #region Constructors

    public AdminModule(
        IUnityContainer container,
        IScreenFactoryRegistry screenFactoryRegistry,
        IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
        IBusyService busyService
        )
        : base(container, screenFactoryRegistry)
    {
        this.EventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.BusyService = busyService;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    protected IEventAggregator EventAggregator { get; set; }
    protected IBusyService BusyService { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    #region Register Screen Factories

    protected override void RegisterScreenFactories()
    {
        this.ScreenFactoryRegistry.Register(ScreenKeyType.ApplicationAdmin, typeof(AdminScreenFactory));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Register Views and Various Services

    protected override void RegisterViewsAndServices()
    {
        //View Models
        this.Container.RegisterType<IAdminViewModel, AdminViewModel>();

               }

    #endregion
```

the code that produces the error is:

```
namespace Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity
    protected virtual IModule CreateModule(string typeName)
        {
            Type moduleType = Type.GetType(typeName);
            if (moduleType == null)
            {
                throw new ModuleInitializeException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.FailedToGetType, typeName));
            }

            return (IModule)this.serviceLocator.GetInstance(moduleType); <-- Error Here
        }
```

Can Anyone Help Me

Error Log Below:

General Information

---

```
Additional Info:
ExceptionManager.MachineName: xxxxx
ExceptionManager.TimeStamp: 22/02/2010 10:16:55 AM
ExceptionManager.FullName: Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.ExceptionManagement, Version=1.0.3591.32238, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
ExceptionManager.AppDomainName: Infinity.vshost.exe
ExceptionManager.ThreadIdentity: 
ExceptionManager.WindowsIdentity: xxxxx
```

1) Exception Information

---

```
Exception Type: Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleInitializeException
ModuleName: AdminModule
Message: An exception occurred while initializing module 'AdminModule'. 
    - The exception message was: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type AdminModule, key ""
    Check the InnerException property of the exception for more information. If the exception occurred 
    while creating an object in a DI container, you can exception.GetRootException() to help locate the 
    root cause of the problem. 
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: Void HandleModuleInitializationError(Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleInfo, System.String, System.Exception)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: Microsoft.Practices.Composite
```

StackTrace Information

---

```
  at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.HandleModuleInitializationError(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, String assemblyName, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.Initialize(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleManager.InitializeModule(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModulesThatAreReadyForLoad()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleManager.OnModuleTypeLoaded(ModuleInfo typeLoadedModuleInfo, Exception error)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.FileModuleTypeLoader.BeginLoadModuleType(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, ModuleTypeLoadedCallback callback)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleManager.BeginRetrievingModule(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModuleTypes(IEnumerable`1 moduleInfos)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModulesWhenAvailable()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleManager.Run()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.InitializeModules()
   at Infinity.Bootstrapper.InitializeModules() in D:\Projects\dotNet\Infinity\source\Inifinty\Infinity\Application Modules\BootStrapper.cs:line 75
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.Run(Boolean runWithDefaultConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.UnityBootstrapper.Run()
   at Infinity.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in D:\Projects\dotNet\Infinity\source\Inifinty\Infinity\App.xaml.cs:line 37
   at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__0(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
```

2) Exception Information

---

```
Exception Type: Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException
Message: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type AdminModule, key ""
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: System.Object GetInstance(System.Type, System.String)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
```

StackTrace Information

---

```
 at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.CreateModule(String typeName)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.Initialize(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
```

3) Exception Information

---

```
Exception Type: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
TypeRequested: AdminModule
NameRequested: NULL
Message: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Infinity.Modules.Admin.AdminModule", name = "". Exception message is: The current build operation (build key Build Key[Infinity.Modules.Admin.AdminModule, null]) failed: The parameter screenFactoryRegistry could not be resolved when attempting to call constructor Infinity.Modules.Admin.AdminModule(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container, PhoenixIT.IScreenFactoryRegistry screenFactoryRegistry, Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Events.IEventAggregator eventAggregator, PhoenixIT.IBusyService busyService). (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: System.Object DoBuildUp(System.Type, System.Object, System.String)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: Microsoft.Practices.Unity

StackTrace Information
*********************************************
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.UnityServiceLocatorAdapter.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)
```

4) Exception Information

---

```
Exception Type: Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildFailedException
ExecutingStrategyTypeName: BuildPlanStrategy
ExecutingStrategyIndex: 3
BuildKey: Build Key[Infinity.Modules.Admin.AdminModule, null]
Message: The current build operation (build key Build Key[Infinity.Modules.Admin.AdminModule, null]) failed: The parameter screenFactoryRegistry could not be resolved when attempting to call constructor Infinity.Modules.Admin.AdminModule(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container, PhoenixIT.IScreenFactoryRegistry screenFactoryRegistry, Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Events.IEventAggregator eventAggregator, PhoenixIT.IBusyService busyService). (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: System.Object ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2
```

StackTrace Information

---

```
 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.Builder.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, ILifetimeContainer lifetime, IPolicyList policies, IStrategyChain strategies, Object buildKey, Object existing)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name)
```

5) Exception Information

---

```
Exception Type: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: The parameter screenFactoryRegistry could not be resolved when attempting to call constructor Infinity.Modules.Admin.AdminModule(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container, PhoenixIT.IScreenFactoryRegistry screenFactoryRegistry, Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Events.IEventAggregator eventAggregator, PhoenixIT.IBusyService busyService).
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: Void ThrowForResolutionFailed(System.Exception, System.String, System.String, Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2
```

StackTrace Information

---

```
at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForResolutionFailed(Exception inner, String parameterName, String constructorSignature, IBuilderContext context)
   at BuildUp_Infinity.Modules.Admin.AdminModule(IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
```

6) Exception Information

---

```
Exception Type: Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildFailedException
ExecutingStrategyTypeName: BuildPlanStrategy
ExecutingStrategyIndex: 3
BuildKey: Build Key[PhoenixIT.IScreenFactoryRegistry, null]
Message: The current build operation (build key Build Key[PhoenixIT.IScreenFactoryRegistry, null]) failed: The current type, PhoenixIT.IScreenFactoryRegistry, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping? (Strategy type BuildPlanStrategy, index 3)
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: System.Object ExecuteBuildUp(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2
```

StackTrace Information

---

```
 at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context)
   at BuildUp_Infinity.Modules.Admin.AdminModule(IBuilderContext )
```

7) Exception Information

---

```
Exception Type: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: The current type, PhoenixIT.IScreenFactoryRegistry, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: Void ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.IBuilderContext)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2
```

StackTrace Information

---

```
  at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(IBuilderContext context)
   at BuildUp_PhoenixIT.IScreenFactoryRegistry(IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
```

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The innermost exception is the issue.

Your Module type needs a parameter called "screenFactoryRegistry" of type IScreenFactoryRegistry.  Since IScreenFactoryRegistry is an interface and you apparently have not done a Register in the container to map that interface to a concrete type, the Unity container throws an exception.

To resolve this, you'd need to map that type in Unity, probably in the ConfigureContainer method of your bootstrapper:

```
Container.RegisterType<IScreenFactoryRegistry, MyScreenFactoryRegistryImplementation>();
```

Comment: In my Bootstrapper I have this::

  private void RegisterApplicationController()
        {
            Container.RegisterType<IScreenFactoryRegistry, ScreenFactoryRegistry>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            Container.RegisterType<ScreenConductor, ScreenConductor>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    // Now crank up the ScreenConductor
            ScreenConductor screenConductor = Container.Resolve<ScreenConductor>();
           // ScreenFactoryRegistry screenFactoryRegistry = Container.Resolve<ScreenFactoryRegistry>();
        }
Is this you mean?

Comment: The Code to Load the factory was being run before the Loading of the Modules.   I swapped them around and all is good.
Thanks for your help